# Detect mouse click anywhere Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm beginner in typescript and angular 2, I have error in my code! Would you please help me to fix this?

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core'  
export class TooltipComponent {
    public show: boolean = false;

    @HostListener('document:click',['$event'])    

    documentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        this.show = false;    
    }

    showTooltip() {
        this.show = true;
        this.documentClick('????');    
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this fully working example https://plnkr.co/edit/jqr1czIu9GZ3DAAidFiG?p=preview

Answer (score 12):

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public documentClick(event: Event): void {
    //doSomething () --> Your logic when there is a document click
  }
```

Question is bit unclear, But the code above would get fired when there is a document click

Answer (score 2):

Other way how to register listener over DOCUMENT ([plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jqr1czIu9GZ3DAAidFiG?p=preview)):

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit, HostListener, VERSION} from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ text }}
    </div>
  `
})
export default class DemoAppComponent implements OnInit{

  public text: string
  public show: boolean

  //constructor
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {

    document.addEventListener('click', this.onDocument1Click);
    this.text =  "Angular " + VERSION.full
  }

  //init
  ngOnInit() { }

  onDocument1Click(){
    this.show = !this.show
    alert(this.show)
  }


  //add hostlistner on document:click
  //@HostListener("document:click", ['$event'])
  //onDocumentClick(event: Event): void {
  //  this.show = !this.show
  //  alert(this.show)
  //}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you create new component, define host property in your new component and use other components

**You can use (document:click) event:**

```
@Component({
  host: {
    '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
  },
})
class SomeComponent() {
  constructor(private _eref: ElementRef) { }

  onClick(event) {
     // Your codes...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

export class TooltipComponent {

    public show: boolean = false;

    clickListener: Function;

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer,
    ) {
        this.clickListener = renderer.listenGlobal(
            'document',
            'click',
            (event: MouseEvent) => this.documentClick(event)
        );
    }

    documentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        console.log(event.target);
        if (!this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
            this.show = false;
        }
    }
}
```