# Why renderer.listen does not trigger change Detection?

Tags: angular, renderer

Why the code does not trigger change Detection?

```
this._renderer.listen('document', 'click'...
```

Is it normal behavior?

Comment: First, why would you use the renderer to listen to document events ?

Comment: I need to know why it does not trigger the change detection

Comment: Again, why would you use the renderer to listen to document events? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247460/detect-mouse-click-anywhere-angular2

Comment: Because HostListener leads to big performance problems.

And again I need to understand why change detection is not triggering in the case.

Comment: renderer might be used to listen scroll of particular element, and the variables inside wont update in template

Comment: so through some answers, I see that the rendrer.listen will not trigger change detection right guys ??